# Wifi stops working when I close and open the laptop lid

Tags: 16.04, wireless, network-manager, macbook-pro

```
OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Memory: 7.7GiB
Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-5257U CPU @ 2.70GHz × 4 
Graphics: Intel® Iris 6100 (Broadwell GT3) 
OS type: 64-bit
Disk: 37.0 GB
Machine: Macbook Pro A5102
uname -a: Linux caleb-macbuntu 4.8.0-41-generic #44~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 3 17:11:16 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
uname -r: 4.8.0-41-generic
```

When I close my laptop lid and open it again, the internet stops working. Browsers, `ping`, whatever. I have to `service network-manager restart` to get it working again. How can I fix this?

Comment: What power saving features are on

Comment: How do I check? I scrolled through `powertop` but I couldn't figure out a config option view